# Using Expressions to determine if string starts with a letter

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need some help building a condition statement within an SSIS Expression that will allow me to filter out a 9 position varchar field that must always start with two alphabetic characters.

Pattern should always follow:  AA0000000

My goal is to have the data flow hit the conditional split and dump the illegal records out to a dump file for later QA.

Example:

- AQ1234567   <-- Legal
- PA9876543   <-- Legal
- RR1133456   <-- Legal
- K12345G65   <-- Illegal
- 098874312   <-- Illegal

I am open to other methods anyone would have to handling this filter. My data is coming from an Excel document to start and unfortunately there is no prevalidation of the data prior to hitting my load process.

Comment: What about `$%1234567`? Is the rule non-numeric or strictly A-Z in the first two positions?

Comment: It will always be A-Z

Comment: The patindex function will help you.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But I am unclear of how patindex will help me here as I am not matching a preset pattern of letters and numbers. I only care if the first two digits are [A-Z] and the rest are [0-9]. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the usage of patindex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restricting my solution to the Expression space, the tool you're looking for is [CODEPOINT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137696.aspx). It returns the integer value of the first character it finds. 
Armed with my handy dandy [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) table, I need to call `CodePoint` on the first and second characters in my source column and test that the values are between the character range for A-Z.

This tests for the first character `CODEPOINT(Src)` and this is the test for the second character `CODEPOINT(SUBSTRING(Src,2,1))`

Putting that logic together results in this ugly expression

```
(CODEPOINT(SUBSTRING(Src,2,1)) >= 65 
    && CODEPOINT(SUBSTRING(Src,2,1)) < 91) 
&& (CODEPOINT(Src) >= 65 
    && CODEPOINT(Src) < 91) ? true : false
```

[image]

My rule of thumb is that when my expressions scroll way off the screen, I prefer to drop the logic into a script component. That or I would break it up into multiple Derived Column Components as it makes the maintenance easier.

Comment: I see your point in regards to splitting it up. I believe this will give me what I need though. Thank you

Comment: It's a shame I can't give this **two** upvotes: one for the answer itself and one for the `My rule of thumb is that when my expressions scroll way off the screen, I prefer to drop the logic into a script component.` comment!